# Unbootable problem with USB root hub (Ubuntu 20.04.05)

Tags: boot, gnome, usb, motherboard

I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 a few days back.  Everything worked great and looked good.  I had some issues with TimeShift and Deja-Dup, which I sorted out.

When I viewed my computer the next morning to check on the backup status - I could not type in the password box.  I use a USB 3.0 4K four-port KVM so sometimes I lose the mouse or keyboard.  I power-cycled the KVM but still could not type in the box.

I remotely connected and rebooted, but was presented with a ton of USB errors and it never got to the Gnome desktop.

After going into recovery mode via GRUB, I discovered the problem was usb 3-1.  Output of lsusb for Bus 003 follows:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Motherboard: Gigabyte X570 Aorus Master - updated to BIOS firmware version F35

Experience: > 40 years, Unix, Mainframes, PCs, RaspberryPi, Sun, HP, Windows, Linux, ...

I can live without any USB 2.0 devices - Ubuntu does not boot if I plug devices into the 2.0 ports, so I suspect something on the motherboard has failed.  I tried disabling the legacy USB ports in the BIOS, but that did not work.

I can purchase a USB 2.0 adapter and install it - but I need to bypass the current issue to use my computer.

Suggestions are welcome - I only have around two years experience with Ubuntu (mostly using the GUI or terminal dealing with fstab, devices, networking), but have done systems-level work on many flavors of Unix and have a ton of hardware experience.

Output from dmesg: (for the first minute - it keeps repeating forever)

```
[    3.009220] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    3.145229] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    3.385451] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    3.625429] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.757337] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    3.997412] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    4.521675] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.522810] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[    4.730504] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[    4.937650] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[    5.065675] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    5.066529] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[    5.274437] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[    5.481665] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[   36.713240] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   36.841253] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   37.081247] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   37.321225] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[   37.457297] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   37.701250] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   38.221235] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[   38.221614] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   38.429611] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   38.641226] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[   38.769233] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[   38.769705] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   38.977699] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   39.185222] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[   49.957239] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[   50.093245] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   50.329250] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   50.565754] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[   50.693934] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   50.929820] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   51.449760] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[   51.450764] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   51.658746] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   51.865916] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 14, error -71
[   51.993575] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[   51.994515] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   52.202718] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   52.409419] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 15, error -71
```

From syslog - about 5 seconds of output: (a repeating pattern starts...)

```
Jan  6 00:00:01 dug02 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2001.0" x-pid="1044" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Jan  6 00:00:01 dug02 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
Jan  6 00:00:01 dug02 systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.
Jan  6 00:00:03 dug02 kernel: [28682.402291] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 88 using xhci_hcd
Jan  6 00:00:03 dug02 kernel: [28682.534744] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jan  6 00:00:03 dug02 kernel: [28682.770637] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jan  6 00:00:03 dug02 kernel: [28683.006700] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 89 using xhci_hcd
Jan  6 00:00:03 dug02 kernel: [28683.134742] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jan  6 00:00:04 dug02 kernel: [28683.370758] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jan  6 00:00:04 dug02 kernel: [28683.478513] usb usb3-port1: attempt power cycle
Jan  6 00:00:04 dug02 kernel: [28683.890689] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 90 using xhci_hcd
Jan  6 00:00:04 dug02 kernel: [28683.891578] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Jan  6 00:00:04 dug02 kernel: [28684.099911] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Jan  6 00:00:05 dug02 kernel: [28684.306707] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 90, error -71
Jan  6 00:00:05 dug02 kernel: [28684.434699] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 91 using xhci_hcd
Jan  6 00:00:05 dug02 kernel: [28684.435641] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Jan  6 00:00:05 dug02 kernel: [28684.643346] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Jan  6 00:00:05 dug02 kernel: [28684.850699] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 91, error -71
Jan  6 00:00:05 dug02 kernel: [28684.851357] usb usb3-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
Jan  6 00:00:05 dug02 kernel: [28684.994291] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 92 using xhci_hcd
Jan  6 00:00:05 dug02 kernel: [28685.126731] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
```

I just want to use my system again - but nothing I have tried so far has worked.  I am willing to disable "Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub" - but my attempts so far have not worked.

Getting into "recovery" mode from GRUB was a challenge - I will try and remove it there - but I am not optimistic.

Update:

I created a USB boot device with Ubuntu 22.04.1 and got some of the same messages when booting, but Gnome started and the messages stopped.  It appears to be a difference between the base and updated versions of 20.04.

Working on unbinding the USB 2.0 root hub - hoping that will get past this problem.

Booting the old system is rough.  The messages going to the console do not stop - I used to know how to redirect them...

With the USB issues - getting into recovery mode only happens in 1 of 40 reboot attempts. (using shift and ESC)

Using the Ubuntu 22.04.1 system does let me poke around and try and fix things - I just need to find the magic bullet.

Update2: Upgraded to 22.04 last night - still having similar issues.  The console shows the same set of errors but now drops into a tty login and will not start Gnome. (manual attempts to start it fail)

I have no network settings when my systems comes up, so I have to manually configure the network for my 10GB adapter.

The system is reachable from rsh/putty but I hope to get Gnome running again so I can get to my VMs I created.  I copied the drives off - so I could get at my data, but my Windows 10 systems data was not really accessible.

Final update: I upgraded to 22.04 using terminal - it did not install Gnome.  I did that and now I can boot to Ubuntu again! :-)

Was getting really tired of using just terminal for everything - felt like I was back in the 1980's on a mainframe - almost.

I still am getting a ton of errors in the logs - but my system is back to normal-ish.  I need to see if I can find a way to disable the USB hub on the motherboard and install a USB 2.0 card.  I suspect that should resolve the hardware issues.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the gory details are in my "question" above.

I installed 22.04 - upgrading from 20.04.05 using terminal.  It skips the Gnome install if you do that.  I needed to manually install Gnome and was able to log back into my system.

I had a few things to sort out (QEMU was not happy).  The BIOS update of my motherboard disabled virtualization.  I had to go back and re-enable it - and some of my settings are missing.  I cannot change the taskbar location - using the GUI.

Timeshift keeps eating all of my storage - I am freeing up some and reducing the frequency and eliminating VM disk files from the backups.

These are minor issues compared to not being able to boot.  I can work with what I have now - which is a lot better then where things were.